# Export Blender Particle System Hair To Three.Js

Tags: mesh, export, particles, physics, three.js

After several months of casual research on three.js as I worked on a model in Blender 2.7 I have yet to locate a method for exporting the blender particle system hair? By chance would anyone have any ideas how would I go about achieving this feat, would I need to perhaps export to OBJ or some other format? I have yet to see any three.js imported particle systems from any 3d system?..Any ideas would greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the hair particles to a mesh in the modifier tab in the properties panel.
[image]

This would only create and object with only edges and vertices:
[image]

If you need meshes with faces you could emit low poly cylinders from the hair particles before converting them to a mesh.

[image]

Comment: Actually that hasn't yet worked? I created a cube and applied a hair particle, applied material color and then selected the modifier "Convert" and then exported to three.js and only the cube appeared?

Comment: I did try several combinations exampled by applying hair only to a vertex group and then exporting and that resulted in the same, just the cube, however, the cubes do look altered? and didn't retain the material color

Comment: I simply utilized a three.js JSON Loader and the simplistic geometry, material callback functions..any ideas?

Comment: It is recommended to use the .obj format, you find an example in three.js examples/webgl_loader_obj Could you add screenshots of what you're actually trying to do? the converted particles are an object(s) itself and need also be loaded in three.js loading only the cube wouldn't have any effect. In case you used the dupli object you would also need to join the instances because for 1000 hair particles you would get 1000 objects.

Comment: The process that you have described has now worked with tweaking! While it worked magnificently when it is imported into three.js it really lacks a realistic appearance! Above you mention utilizing, emitting "low Poly Cylinders" I'll give that a try...any pointers, good ideas?

Comment: @user2544743 Just create another object and select it as DupliObject in the particle settings (render), see the last image of my post. Not that you need to scale it appropiately. After conversion to mesh you have a mesh with faces that should display fine.

Comment: Okay! That looks a little more impressive great work! Curiously, are you then simply creating vertex groups and grouping the particles, cylinders for manipulation, shaping?

Answer (score 0):

I will add an answer here that I have mentioned in a previous issue that I can no longer find.

What you do is convert your hair system, under the modifier panel. This will convert your hair to a mesh of only edges.

Next you apply the "screw" modifier. Set the **axis** to *Z Axis*, **angle** to *2 degrees*. Set the **steps** to 2 and **render steps** to 2 by typing it in.

You can mess with the axis options, and even AxisOb (axis object) to tweat the way everything is extruded.

Than you just export the mesh hair to THREE.js like any other mesh.

Good luck!