# Convert particle hair to anime-style mesh hair and keep all physics animation

Tags: mesh, physics

Blender's hair tools are very nice for, well, making hair. I would like to convert hair that has been styled and animated into a mesh while keeping the animation. [Export Blender Particle System Hair To Three.Js](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/export-blender-particle-system-hair-to-three-js) details converting hair to a mesh, but afterwards the hair is no longer animated by physics. Physics based animation is a must for me in this case.

I'm willing to consider other ways of making hair if I have to.

Comment: I think that you may use cloth simulation, but I'm realy not sure and I don't know how.

Comment: The short, and unsatisfactory answer, is that you can't right now. The closest you can come is converting the hair to mesh, then converting to curves and giving them a bevel and taper, and then run softbodies on the curves. This doesn't give very good results though.

Comment: It seems [this guy](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?389493-Converting-Hair-object-particles-to-Animated-Meshes-problem-with-python-script) has succeeded but I don't know how exactly since I have no python knowledge.